# How to index a Blog as a search engine?

Tags: php, python, search, search-engine, web-crawler

I want to create a **simple search engine** for learning purpose.

I want to know **how to index a simple blog site**.

A blog site has many pages and in every page there is a blogpost.
But in every page there are other stuff in common as well ( header, footer, category block and other stuff ).

In your opinion, **How can I index this blog ?**

The program language doesn't matter obviously.

Comment: Why would you index it any differently than another page? As far as I know Google treats every single website individually, not recognizing or caring if the websites belong to the same domain.

Comment: Please be more specific with the question. This is a whole research field, what your talking about.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the quite powerfull Zend Lucene search engine for that (PHP 5).

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.html